# How to create a form in infopath hosted in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, microsoft-access

I am looking to create a form in infopath which I will be hosting in SharePoint which in turn will be accessed by the user using a browser. Once the user fills out the form and submits, I want to grab the data and populate a Access database table.

I know most likely I have to use a web service but because I am new to SharePoint, I would really appreciate some guidance or if there are any examples that can be shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser based forms can't submit to a database - http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/infopath-help/submit-form-data-to-a-microsoft-access-database-HA010211754.aspx

So you'll need to write a custom web service that you can submit InfoPath to that will write to your access database.

This article provides a walkthrough of exactly what you wnat to do (write to Access via web service, and call that from InfoPath on submit): http://www.hoonzis.com/submit-entire-infopath-form-to-web/